# How to register enteries in the registry for ALLUSERS and CurrentUser separately

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield

I want to install registry values from a REG file based on (Anyone who uses this computer) AllUsers or Only for me (Current User) using InstallShield Basic MSI project.

If the user selects All Users then the registry entries should go to [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]. If the user select Current User then the registry entries should go to HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID

Kindly help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer does this by default. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is automatically redirected to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes for a per-user installation.

You can read more about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How to avoid the prompt dialog for user approval in case of per-user installation(HKEY_CURRENT_USER)??

Comment: Make sure that the installation doesn't write in any per-machine location (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Program Files etc.). For example, a per-user installation should use a location in the user profile folder.

Comment: is this possible to use C\Program File\Application Name? I am new to Installshield. Where to set user profile folder in installshield?? Thanks

Comment: Program Files is a per-machine location, so it requires Administrator privileges. You can use it, but your installer will request elevation.

Comment: Tried with user profile folder (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\) but it still request the elevation.

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield's  Registry  view shows the  hives HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_USER_SELECTABLE.   Import your REG file and it will associate with either HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.   Then drag the keys that were imported to the HKEY_USER_SELECTABLE hive.    Now the keys will be created based on Per-User or Per-Machine (ALLUSERS property ) during the install.

Also, if you you tell InstallShield to extract the COM data from your DLL's ( instead of using your regfile )  then the COM metadata will go into the COM "tables" ( AppId, ProgId, Class et al ) and Windows Installer will still either record the data to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Classes or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Classes based on the Per-User / Per-Machine concept.